# How do I beat the Bearington Ballers?

Tags: ninja-village

You'd think a bunch of baseball players would be pushovers for ninjas, but they have these annoying bats that like to knock my cannon shots out of the air.  Also, they have a ton of health.  I swapped all my gunners over to archers and yet I still cannot do enough damage to defeat them in 3 turns using mostly level 8-11 ninjas.  What can I do to beat them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about 30 tries I finally managed to do it.

Offense is the name of the game here, my final setup was like this:

Infantry:

- 3x Chain attackers front row with all offense gear (best sword, highest atk cap, best armor, and best healing potion)
- 3x Strong attackers (or 2x and 1 strategist) middle row with the same equipment, but with bombs instead of potions for a little more damage.
- Last row will be the raven, wolf, and dog (let your archers hold them instead).

Calvary:

- 3x Strong attackers with highest damage gear, one of them being a strategist can help a little.

Archery:

- Fill the remaining slots with archers, as many as you can get, wearing all + marksmanship gear and the strongest bow.  Also, for their extra slot give them  the crow, wolf, dog, boar, and bear (don't give them the beaver since that takes up a front slot on the infantry and you can't afford to use it there).  At least 1 strategist recommended.

Hopefully with a little luck you'll be able to beat them within the 3 turn limit.  If not, you'll have to train your ninjas up more.

Answer (score 0):

Totally forgo defense. Just go for maximum firepower. 
I had my usual team with melee resist4, projectile proof (x1) and they were all maxed out at lvl30 and STILL couldnt beat them (like 9~15 archers remaining).

I totally lost it and decided to abandon all the time i spent leveling them; just went for firepower. i wanted to max their levels too but i attempted before i even maxed out (itchy fingers) and succeeded...

calvary: strategy4 (kimura lvl30)
archer: all the rapid shots3 (fukuyo26 oshiyama30 akagawa30 dorifu25) strategy4 (shishimaru)
infantry: all the chain attacks (miyamoto30 jon30 nakano28 date19 takenaga23)strategy4 (asaryu)